# How to use custom directive in a T4 template?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, t4

I created a custom T4 directive processor in one project, and now I want to use the processor in a T4 template in another project, but I'm receiving the following error:

> The type '`MyNamespace.MyCustomDirectiveProcessor`' of the directive
>   processor named '`MyCustomDirectiveProcessor`' does not derive from
>   `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.DirectiveProcessor`. The
>   transformation will not be run.

My directive processor class is defined like this:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyCustomDirectiveProcessor : DirectiveProcessor
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

*What do I need to do to make the custom directive work?* I've followed the guidelines in [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138364%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to add the directive processor to the registry. I do so in the post build step of the project where I've defined my directive processor class, and I've made sure that the project is built and the registry keys are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging around, I discovered the issue here. Turns out I was using an older version of **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.dll**. The version I had was **8.1.0.0**, as listed in the Add Reference dialog.

Once I installed the [Visual Studio 2008 SDK 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=508), I saw that I had a new version: **9.0.0.0**. When I built my project linking to the new version of the .DLL, everything worked swimmingly.

Hope this helps some poor lost soul still on VS2008!